# How to bind the width to the widest successor (recurrently any child of any child)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, data-binding

I'm using the syntax below.

```
<Canvas Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Beep}">
  ...
</Canvas>
```

At the moment, *Beep* is the widest control under the canvas but it's not guaranteed to remain like that. I'd need to bind the width to whichever successor (i.e. any child's child, recurrently speaking) of the canvas that is the widest.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it but you may try something like this.
In xaml:

```
<local:Converter x:Key="converter"/>
<Canvas Width="{Binding Path=Children, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Converter="{StaticResource converter}"">

</Canvas>
```

And the converter may be something similar to this one:

```
public class Converter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        UIElementCollection children=value as UIElementCollection;
        double ret=0.0;
        recursiveSearch(children, ref ret);
        return ret;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    private void recursiveSearch(UIElementCollection children, ref double width)
    {
        if(children == null || children.Count==0) return;
        foreach(UIElement element in children)
        {
            FrameworkElement el=element as FrameworkElement;
            if(el == null) continue;
            if(el.ActualWidth>width) width=el.ActualWidth;
            Panel p=el as Panel;
            if(p!=null) recursiveSearch(p.Children, ref width);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to bind to the collection of all control which width interests you. Then write a converter and choose from the collection the widest control.

If you don't have a collection of controls you can also use multibinding of course.

Comment: Sounds like if it's easier to set a fix width that **should** exceed all the others... Or am I overestimating how much code that'd need? Care to give some code samples or is it a larger job? (In the latter case, I'll just do it the Q&D way, hehe.)